# Best practice question on merging bug fixes w/ the release branching pattern on SVN 1.6

Tags: svn

I am switching to using the release branching pattern. I know the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.release) say that in the release branching pattern, you make your bug fixes in the trunk and the merge them into the release branch. The book was written for SVN 1.5 and there have been improvements to the information SVN stores when branching and merging in 1.6.  If I never plan on merging the release branch back to the trunk, is there any danger in making the changes in the release branch and merge the fixes into the trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we follow as release process:

1. Develop for new release in trunk, until we finalize the trunk is ready for final testing and release.
2. At this time, we create a new branch by copying the trunk. Lets say this branch is `branch-2.1`. There is no new feature going to be added to this branch. Only testing and bug fixes.
3. New code keep on adding to trunk for `version 2.2`. (so, you see there are two branches `trunk` and `branch-2.1` are actively developed)
4. At the end of every day, we merge `branch-2.1` with the trunk, so that any fixes made in `branch-2.1` reflects in trunk as well. (earlier we used to do this process just before releasing the branch, we found out that creates bigger mess)
5. When `branch-2.1` is mature enough, we create a tag and release this.

So, you see, it very common practice to make changes to branch and merge them back to trunk.

You can see this other question answered by me on release step [release from SVN using "export" and then? how to upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151760/release-from-svn-using-export-and-then-how-to-upgrade/5151821#5151821)